# Looping dynamic JSON to get all nodes C#

Tags: c#, json

I have multiple JSON files I need to loop and get certain details from these. However, I would like to have a one size fits all loop as the child nodes match one another in regards to properties. Can anyone suggest how I could loop my JSON nodes?

Example:

```
{
    "name": "Example",
    "description": "Example JSON",
    "properties":  {
         "foo": "bar",
         "foo1": "bar2",
         "foo3": "bar4",
    },
    "stages":  {
         "This is a stage": {
              "stageInfo1": "blah",
              "stageInfo2": "blah",
              "integration": {
                  "x": "x",
                  "y": "y",
                  "z": "z"
              }
         },
         "Another Stage": {
              "stageInfo1": "blah",
              "stageInfo2": "blah",
              "integration": {
                  "x": "x",
                  "y": "y",
                  "z": "z"
              }
         }
    }
 }
```

There can be hundreds of stages. But the pattern of the JSON follows this general pattern, the stages can have random names, but they contain the same definition.

Any simple suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The [NewtonSoft JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) will do the heavy lifting for you. It wraps a json document as a kind of dynamic object with a LINQable interface. Most templates for a .Net project will pull in a NuGet dependency on the  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json package which provides it.

```
void Main()
{
    var json = @"{
        ""name"": ""Example"",

        ""description"": ""Example JSON"",
        ""properties"":  {
        ""foo"": ""bar"",
             ""foo1"": ""bar2"",
             ""foo3"": ""bar4"",
        },
        ""stages"":  {
        ""This is a stage"": {
            ""stageInfo1"": ""blah"",
                  ""stageInfo2"": ""blah"",
                  ""integration"": {
                ""x"": ""x"",
                      ""y"": ""y"",
                      ""z"": ""z""

                  }
        },
             ""Another Stage"": {
            ""stageInfo1"": ""blah"",
                  ""stageInfo2"": ""blah"",
                  ""integration"": {
                ""x"": ""x"",
                      ""y"": ""y"",
                      ""z"": ""z""

                  }
        }
    }
     }";

    var jo = JObject.Parse(json);

    Console.WriteLine("A couple of ways to access just one level of ( Path,Value(s) ) pairs --------------------------------------------");
    foreach (var node in jo) { Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", node.Key, node.Value); }
    Console.WriteLine("--- Or this --------------------------------------------");
    foreach (var jtoken in jo.Children()) { Console.WriteLine("{0}={1} | has {2} children", jtoken.Path, string.Join(",\n", jtoken.Values()),  jtoken.Children().Count()); };

    Console.WriteLine("\n\n------------------- But to walk the full tree, use recursion----------------------------------------\n");
    WriteRecursively(jo);
}

void WriteRecursively(JToken topJToken)
{
    foreach (var jtoken in topJToken.Children())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}={1} | has {2} children", jtoken.Path, string.Join(",\n", jtoken.Values()), jtoken.Children().Count());
        WriteRecursively(jtoken);
    };
}
```

Output :

```
A couple of ways to access just one level of ( Path,Value(s) ) pairs --------------------------------------------
    name Example
    description Example JSON
    properties {
      "foo": "bar",
      "foo1": "bar2",
      "foo3": "bar4"
    }
    stages {
      "This is a stage": {
        "stageInfo1": "blah",
        "stageInfo2": "blah",
        "integration": {
          "x": "x",
          "y": "y",
          "z": "z"
        }
      },
      "Another Stage": {
        "stageInfo1": "blah",
        "stageInfo2": "blah",
        "integration": {
          "x": "x",
          "y": "y",
          "z": "z"
        }
      }
    }
    --- Or this --------------------------------------------
    name=Example | has 1 children
    description=Example JSON | has 1 children
    properties="foo": "bar",
    "foo1": "bar2",
    "foo3": "bar4" | has 1 children
    stages="This is a stage": {
      "stageInfo1": "blah",
      "stageInfo2": "blah",
      "integration": {
        "x": "x",
        "y": "y",
        "z": "z"
      }
    },
    "Another Stage": {
      "stageInfo1": "blah",
      "stageInfo2": "blah",
      "integration": {
        "x": "x",
        "y": "y",
        "z": "z"
      }
    } | has 1 children


    ------------------- But to walk the full tree, use recursion----------------------------------------

    name=Example | has 1 children
    name= | has 0 children
    description=Example JSON | has 1 children
    description= | has 0 children
    properties="foo": "bar",
    "foo1": "bar2",
    "foo3": "bar4" | has 1 children
    properties=bar,
    bar2,
    bar4 | has 3 children
    properties.foo=bar | has 1 children
    properties.foo= | has 0 children
    properties.foo1=bar2 | has 1 children
    properties.foo1= | has 0 children
    properties.foo3=bar4 | has 1 children
    properties.foo3= | has 0 children
    stages="This is a stage": {
      "stageInfo1": "blah",
      "stageInfo2": "blah",
      "integration": {
        "x": "x",
        "y": "y",
        "z": "z"
      }
    },
    "Another Stage": {
      "stageInfo1": "blah",
      "stageInfo2": "blah",
      "integration": {
        "x": "x",
        "y": "y",
        "z": "z"
      }
    } | has 1 children
    stages={
      "stageInfo1": "blah",
      "stageInfo2": "blah",
      "integration": {
        "x": "x",
        "y": "y",
        "z": "z"
      }
    },
    {
      "stageInfo1": "blah",
      "stageInfo2": "blah",
      "integration": {
        "x": "x",
        "y": "y",
        "z": "z"
      }
    } | has 2 children
    stages['This is a stage']="stageInfo1": "blah",
    "stageInfo2": "blah",
    "integration": {
      "x": "x",
      "y": "y",
      "z": "z"
    } | has 1 children
    stages['This is a stage']=blah,
    blah,
    {
      "x": "x",
      "y": "y",
      "z": "z"
    } | has 3 children
    stages['This is a stage'].stageInfo1=blah | has 1 children
    stages['This is a stage'].stageInfo1= | has 0 children
    stages['This is a stage'].stageInfo2=blah | has 1 children
    stages['This is a stage'].stageInfo2= | has 0 children
    stages['This is a stage'].integration="x": "x",
    "y": "y",
    "z": "z" | has 1 children
    stages['This is a stage'].integration=x,
    y,
    z | has 3 children
    stages['This is a stage'].integration.x=x | has 1 children
    stages['This is a stage'].integration.x= | has 0 children
    stages['This is a stage'].integration.y=y | has 1 children
    stages['This is a stage'].integration.y= | has 0 children
    stages['This is a stage'].integration.z=z | has 1 children
    stages['This is a stage'].integration.z= | has 0 children
    stages['Another Stage']="stageInfo1": "blah",
    "stageInfo2": "blah",
    "integration": {
      "x": "x",
      "y": "y",
      "z": "z"
    } | has 1 children
    stages['Another Stage']=blah,
    blah,
    {
      "x": "x",
      "y": "y",
      "z": "z"
    } | has 3 children
    stages['Another Stage'].stageInfo1=blah | has 1 children
    stages['Another Stage'].stageInfo1= | has 0 children
    stages['Another Stage'].stageInfo2=blah | has 1 children
    stages['Another Stage'].stageInfo2= | has 0 children
    stages['Another Stage'].integration="x": "x",
    "y": "y",
    "z": "z" | has 1 children
    stages['Another Stage'].integration=x,
    y,
    z | has 3 children
    stages['Another Stage'].integration.x=x | has 1 children
    stages['Another Stage'].integration.x= | has 0 children
    stages['Another Stage'].integration.y=y | has 1 children
    stages['Another Stage'].integration.y= | has 0 children
    stages['Another Stage'].integration.z=z | has 1 children
    stages['Another Stage'].integration.z= | has 0 children
```

Comment: Really elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just model the data into classes and use a deserializer lib like Newtonsoft.JSON

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public class Stage
    {
        [JsonProperty("stageInfo1")]
        public string StageInfo1;
    }

    public class JsonData
    {
        [JsonProperty("stages")]
        public Dictionary<string, Stage> Stages;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = @"{
    ""name"": ""Example"",
    ""description"": ""Example JSON"",
    ""properties"":  {
         ""foo"": ""bar"",
         ""foo1"": ""bar2"",
         ""foo3"": ""bar4"",
    },
    ""stages"":  {
         ""This is a stage"": {
              ""stageInfo1"": ""blah"",
              ""stageInfo2"": ""blah"",
              ""integration"": {
                  ""x"": ""x"",
                  ""y"": ""y"",
                  ""z"": ""z""
              }
         },
         ""Another Stage"": {
              ""stageInfo1"": ""blah"",
              ""stageInfo2"": ""blah"",
              ""integration"": {
                  ""x"": ""x"",
                  ""y"": ""y"",
                  ""z"": ""z""
              }
         }
    }
 }";
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(data.Stages.Keys.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: If it follows a recursive pattern, you can reuse the definitions... without knowing the structure, don't know how to recommend something.

Comment: What if "stages": []? Currently this breaks.

Comment: @Dan if stages is an array, you need to change the type in the model from `Dictionary` to `List` or array (`Stage[]`).

Comment: Hi Andrew, the stages are either exactly as above, or stages: [], I need to be able to handle both types. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Dan you need to create a custom JsonSerializer that knows how to differentiate between the cases based on... something.

Comment: This approach doesn't address the "dynamic" aspect of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following method:

```cs
private IEnumerable<(string path, string key, string value)> GetNodes(JToken token)
{
    foreach (var jt in token.Children())
    {
        if (!jt.Children().Any())
        {
            yield return (
                path: jt.Path,
                key: jt.Path.Split('.').Last(),
                value: jt.ToString()
            );
        }

        foreach (var (path, key, value) in GetNodes(jt))
        {
            yield return (path, key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```cs
var jo = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var valueTuples = GetNodes(jo).ToList();
```

For your dataset, it will yield:

[image]